# Why isnt my program printing out what i want it to?

Tags: java, algorithm

When I run my code my out put is this

> ----jGRASP exec: java AgeClientFL
>
> Enter birth day: 5 Enter birth month: 5 Enter birth year: 5 Birth:
> 5/5/5
>
> Today: 1/1/0 Age: 0
>
> Michaels Birth: 5/7/1995 Milestone: 5/7/2016
> Age at Milestone: 0
>
> ----jGRASP: operation complete.

For `Today` I had entered in 10/10/10 and I want it to come out as 10/10/10 but it came out as 1/1/0. For the first `age` I wanted to get out a 5 but got a 0. And `Age at Milestone` should have been a 21 not 0.

Which parts of my code are causing these incorrect print outs and how can i fix them? Here is part 1 of the code i am using.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class AgeClientFL {

public static void main(String [] args){

  int month, day, year, age;
  
  
  day = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter birth day: ",false); // String mode
  month = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter birth month: ",false);
  year = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter birth year: ",false);
  
  SimpleDate dateBirth = new SimpleDate(month,day,year);
  
  System.out.println("Birth: " + dateBirth);
  
  day = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter todays day: ",true); // JOptionPane mode
  month = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter todays month: ",true);
  year = UtilsFL.readInt("Enter todays year: ",true);
  
  SimpleDate dateToday = new SimpleDate(month,day,year);
  
  System.out.println("Today: " + dateToday);
  
  age = UtilsFL.getAge(dateBirth,dateToday);
  System.out.println("Age: " + age);
  
  month = 5;
  day = 7;
  year = 2016;
  SimpleDate milestone = new SimpleDate(month,day,year);
  month=5;
  day=7;
  year=1995;
  SimpleDate bdMilestone = new SimpleDate(month,day,year);
  int mAge;
  mAge = UtilsFL.getAge(bdMilestone, milestone);
  System.out.println("Michaels Birth: " + bdMilestone);
  System.out.println("Milestone: " + milestone);
  System.out.println("Age at Milestone: " + mAge);
  
}
}
```

And here is part two.

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;    

public class UtilsFL {


public static int readInt(String prompt,boolean guiFlag) {

    if (guiFlag==false){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int data;
    
    System.out.print(prompt);
    data = input.nextInt();
    
    return data;
    }
    else if (guiFlag==true) {
    int data;
    data = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt));
    }
    return 0;
    
  }      
    



public static SimpleDate today() {


    Calendar todayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDate todayDate = new SimpleDate();
    

    todayDate.setDate(todayCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, 
                      todayCal.get(Calendar.DATE),
                      todayCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    return todayDate;
}


public static int getAge(SimpleDate dateBd) {
    int age;
    SimpleDate dateToday = today();
    
    
    age = getAge(dateBd, dateToday);  
    return age;
    
} 

public static int getAge(SimpleDate dateBd, SimpleDate dateRef) {
  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar ();
  Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
    int rAge = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 if((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
   || (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
   && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))))
 {
    rAge--;
 }
    return rAge;
    
    
}
        
}
```

I think it might be a problem with the `public static int getAge` at the bottom of part two of my code. but im not sure and i cant figure out how to fix it.

Here is the code for the SimpleDate class that is referenced in some of my previous code.

```
import java.io.Serializable;        // for object I/O to file

//public class SimpleDate
public class SimpleDate implements Serializable

{
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  /** default constructor
  *  sets month to 1, day to 1 and year to 2000
  */
  public SimpleDate( )
  {
    setDate( 1, 1, 2000 );
  }

  /** overloaded constructor
  *  @param mm    initial value for month
  *  @param dd    initial value for day
  *  @param yyyy  initial value for year
  *
  *  passes parameters to set methods
  */
  public SimpleDate( int mm, int dd, int yyyy )
  {
    setMonth( mm );
    setYear( yyyy );
    setDay( dd );
  }

  /* accessor methods */
  int getMonth( ) { return month; }
  int getDay( )   { return day; }
  int getYear( )  { return year; }

  /** mutator method */
  /** setMonth
  *  @param mm new value for month
  *  if mm is between 1 and 12, sets month to mm
  *  otherwise, sets month to 1
  */
  public void setMonth( int mm )
  {
    month = ( mm >= 1 && mm <= 12 ? mm : 1 );
  }

  /** setDay
  *  @param dd new value for day
  *  if dd is legal day for current month, sets day to dd
  *  otherwise, sets day to 1
  */
  public void setDay( int dd )
  {
    day = ( dd >= 1 && isValidDay( dd ) ? dd : 1 );
  }

  /** setYear
  *  @param yyyy new value for year
  *  sets year to yyyy
  */
  public void setYear( int yyyy )
  {
    year = yyyy;
  }

  /** sets date to the next day
  */
  public void nextDay( )
  {
     if ( ! isValidDay( ++day ) )
     {
         day = 1;
         if ( ++month > 12 )
         {
             month = 1;
             year++;
         }
     }
  }

  private boolean isValidDay( int newDay )
  {
     int [] daysInMonth = { 0, 31, 28, 31,
                                30, 31, 30,
                                31, 31, 30,
                               31, 30, 31 };

    if ( newDay > daysInMonth[month] )
    {
       if ( month == 2 && isLeapYear( ) && newDay == 29 )
          return true;
       else
          return false;
    }
    else
       return true;

  }

  private boolean isLeapYear( )
  {
     return !( year % 4 != 0
               ||( year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0 ) );
  }


  /** setDate
  *  @param mm    new value for month
  *  @param dd    new value for day
  *  @param yyyy  new value for year
  *  passes parameters to setMonth, setDay, and setYear
  */
  public void setDate( int mm, int dd, int yyyy )
  {
    setYear( yyyy );  // set year first (could be leap year)
    setMonth( mm );   // set month next
    setDay( dd );     // set day
  }

  /** toString
  *  @return String
  *  returns date in mm/dd/yyyy format
  */
  public String toString( )
  {
    return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  }

  /** equals
  *  @param   d  Object to compare to this object
  *  @return  true if d is equal to this object
  *           false, otherwise
  */
  public boolean equals( Object d )
  {
    if ( !( d instanceof SimpleDate ) )
       return false;
    SimpleDate d1 = (SimpleDate)d;
    if ( month == d1.month
         && day == d1.day
         && year == d1.year )
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix the problem? Merely posting all your code here won't help.

Comment: @mjuarez well i think it might be a problem with the `public static int getAge` at the bottom of part two of my code. I cant really say what ive tried ive just been witching things around but been getting errors back so i just return it to this.

Comment: what is `SimpleDate`??

Comment: @RC. its a class ill upload the code for that too?

Comment: I know its a class but you should show us its code.

Comment: I though it is SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Look at your `getAge` and how the `Calendar`s there are initialized... Oh, and BTW, it is bad habit to pass date parameters in the weird American order "month, day, year". Most, if not all, standard functions expect it in the "year, month, day" order...

Comment: @glglgl Soo what its doing is theyre both grabbing the same date and comparing them right?..

Comment: @michaelwood Exactly. That's one reason why it doesn't work. AFAICS, `getAge()` doesn't need the `Calendar`s at all; you just could work with `SimpleDate.getYear()` and the other getters.

Answer (score 1):

In your method `UtilsFL#readInt`, you forgot to return `data` in GUI mode:

```
public static int readInt(String prompt, boolean guiFlag) {
    if (guiFlag == false) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int data;

        System.out.print(prompt);
        data = input.nextInt();

        return data;
    } else if (guiFlag == true) {
        int data;
        data = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt));
        // HERE: you need to return data
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So in GUI mode you always get 0. You might also want to simplify the `== true`, `== false`, ...